# Is it leisure time or just leisure?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrases

The noun leisure as defined in the Canadian Oxford dictionary is:

> 1. Free time; time at one's own disposal.
> 2. Enjoyment of free time.
>
>    *[usu. foll. by for, or to + infin.]* opportunity afforded by free time.

And similarly in New Oxford American Dictionary:

> 1. use of free time for enjoyment: increased opportunities for leisure | *[as adj.]* leisure activities.
> 2. **(leisure for/to do something)** opportunity afforded by free time to do something: writers with enough leisure to practice their art.

Since; they both have time defined implicitly; which of the following phrases is correct?

> 1. I've been modifying it in my **leisure**.
> 2. I've been modifying it in my **leisure time**.

Although I think the first one is correct; but the second one is what I have seen generally. Also, the second one sounds right(?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **leisure** (n)
>
> Freedom from time-consuming duties, responsibilities, or activities.

Consequently we can see that

> (X) I've been modifying it in my leisure.
>
> I've been modifying it in my leisure time.

Note that there is also the idiomatic phrase **at (one's) leisure** meaning "When you have time; at your convenience"

> Here is the text. Please feel free to review it **at your leisure**.

Comment: I guess I can rewrite the first like this: "I've been modifying it **at** my leisure." ?

Comment: @hjpotter92: "At your leisure" and "in your leisure time" are subtly different. If your boss calls you on holiday, you might be taking the call during your leisure time (i.e. when you should be having fun) without it being at your leisure (i.e. you don't get to choose when the phone call happens).

Answer (score 1):

You can say *leisure time* as in "Make the most of your leisure time!" or say *leisure* as in "These days we have more money and more leisure to enjoy it." You can also use *leisure* as attributive, as in "the leisure industry."